# Apache WSGI permission error using django logging on production server

Tags: django, apache, wsgi, selinux

Here is some software information

Django 1.8.1
Apache2
Fedora 21

error_log output

```
mod_wsgi (pid=8272): Target WSGI script '/var/www/anime/anime/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=8272): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/anime/anime/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 557, in configure
     handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 725, in configure_handler
     result = factory(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 999, in __init__
     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1023, in _open
     return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/anime/log/info.log'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/anime/anime/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
     application = get_wsgi_application()
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/django_project/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup()
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/django_project/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/django_project/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 86, in configure_logging
     logging_config_func(logging_settings)
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 789, in dictConfig
     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 565, in configure
     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
 ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/anime/log/info.log'
```

Here is the permission mask on the file

```
drwxrwxrwx. 2 apache apache 21 May 28 15:22 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 apache apache 90 May 28 14:53 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache  0 May 28 15:22 info.log
```

I have already searched SOF on all the possible solutions and none of them works. Therefore I suspect that it has something to do with SELinux setting? If it is, can someone tell me which flag do i need to set to true?

Comment: Maybe search outside of StackOverflow. http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html

Comment: I have managed to isolate the cause of the problem. So it works when i have setenforce 0. Of course that is not really the way to do it. So I will need to set httpd_sys_content_t rw for apache. Do you know what is the command to do it? I have seen such command before, But unable to find it online.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reading up on SELinux, I have figured out the solution for this permission error. And I hope that it will help the others who have encountered similar situation when deploying on production server under RHEL linux.

Basically running the command ls -Z shows the following

```
drwxr-xr-x. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 log
```

the folder is labelled with httpd_sys_content_t which does not allow httpd to have write access the the folder. Therefore we need to change this label to httpd_sys_rw_content_t

Firstly, we need to add an entry to the fcontext to inform SELinux what is the default label for files, that will be created, in this folder.

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/path/to/directory(/.*)?"
```

This will add an entry to the fcontext file (/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local)

Next we need to update all the labels of the files in the folder using restorecon.

```
sudo restorecon -R -v /path/to/directory
```

And now the permission error related to the django logging will be gone from the httpd error_log =)